# In exception log i am getting this error in Magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3, exception-error

An element with a "root" ID already exists.

> {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): An
>   element with a \"root\" ID already exists. at
>   vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:157)"}

Comment: Please explain briefly. When you got this error?, what are you trying to do.

Comment: I am getting this error not frequently when browsing the category menu and adding the product .In exception log only i am seeing this error not showing in frontend.